# divs defined using 960grid system css going out of the expandable div in which it is placed

Tags: html, css

I'm using 12 column 960 grid system to design my layout. Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="topStrip"></div>
    <div class='container_12 content'>
        <div class="topStrip"></div>
        <div class="menuStrip">
            <div class="grid_3 menu"></div>
        </div><!-- end menuStrip -->
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="grid_4  dash_1"></div>
        </div><!-- end mainContent -->
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div><!-- end content -->
```

You can check the CSS in jsFiddle links provided below.

The problem is the field inside `.mainContent` Div i.e., `.dash_1` is going out of the `.content` div - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmKPb/7/).

However, if i remove the `.grid_4` and increase `.dash_1` from div inside `.mainContent` it is expanding accordingly - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMXJp/2/).

This might be a simple problem with CSS however I'm breaking my head finding it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem... I run the jsfiddle and test it under firebug. all divs are in place. Am I missing somthing? BTW, what about using **<div class="clear"></div>** between different parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **grid_4** have **float** on it. you have to clear his parent (mainContent). Write like this:

```
.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Read this for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PmKPb/8/

Comment: nice link by the way as mentioned in the link i will go with clearing div, as overflow:hidden seems to have compatibility problems

Answer (score 0):

That is because grid_4 width is 300px

See this

```
.container_12 .grid_4 {
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: width was not the concern height was the concern however it is solved now check the answer of sandeep